# Bootstrap button not aligned in center after aligning with CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently following the ruby on rails tutorial by Michael Hartl, and I'm currently using Bootstrap version 3. The issue is my button is not aligning in the center like the text is

this is what its supposed to look like[image]

however mine looks like
[image]

the changes in tutorial that aligns the text and button comes after implementing these CSS styles:[image]

Can someone guide me in the right direction? the code for my Jumbotron is this:

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

   <h2>
       This is the home page for the
       <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
       sample application.
   </h2>

     <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
  </div>

 <%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

I'll admit, i'm not great with CSS, otherwise i would have figured this out myself
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adding     center-block class  to the div will do

```
    <div class="center-block jumbotron">

    </div>
```

now this jumbotron will be aligned centre.

Edit: As of 2016, you can use the `text-centre` class to do this.

Comment: Would you provide a little example please?

Answer (score 1):

Add `center` class to your `jumbotron` `div`.

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
   This is the home page for the
   <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
   sample application.
  </h2>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
</div>
```

Comment: How come i have to add a center to my jumbotron?

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer, because you want to center it within your jumbotron.  Take a look at some CSS tips & tricks: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html